# R: Matching on closest date (efficiency issue)

Tags: r, date, data.table, matching

```
dt1 <- data.table(x = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c"),
                  y = c("2016-03-01", "2016-05-10", "2016-04-14", "2016-06-25", "2016-01-12"))

   x          y
1: a 2016-03-01
2: a 2016-05-10
3: b 2016-04-14
4: b 2016-06-25
5: c 2016-01-12

dt2 <- data.table(x = c("a", "b", "b", "a"),
                  y = c("2016-05-13", "2016-04-16", "2016-06-20", "2016-02-28"),
                  z = c("1", "1", "2", "3"))

   x          y z
1: a 2016-05-13 1
2: b 2016-04-16 1
3: b 2016-06-20 2
4: a 2016-02-28 3

close.match <- function(dt1x, dt1y, threshold <= 3){
  if(dt1x %in% dt2$x){
    if(abs(as.numeric(as.Date(dt1y) - as.Date(dt2[x == dt1x][which.min(abs(as.Date(y) - as.Date(dt1y))),y]))) < threshold){
      return(dt2[x == dt1x][which.min(abs(as.Date(y) - as.Date(dt1y))),z])
    } else {
      "unknown"
    }
  } else {
    "unknown"
  }
}

dt1[,z:=dt1[,close.match(x,y),by=1:nrow(dt1)][,V1]]

   x          y       z
1: a 2016-03-01       3
2: a 2016-05-10       1
3: b 2016-04-14       1
4: b 2016-06-25 unknown
5: c 2016-01-12 unknown
```

Idea is that there are two events `dt1` and `dt2` with timestamp `y` for every `x`, there can be more than one entry for every `x`, having different timestamp. Expected output is to add column `z` to `dt1` with value from `dt2$z` if two events for matching `x` happen within 3 days from each other. Return "unknown" otherwise.

The code above works and does just that. But problem is vectorization - it is extremely inefficient. Hoping to find any ideas on how to solve this sort of problems in more efficient manner.

Comment: Use `ifelse` to vectorize?

Comment: Why are you running `as.Date` by row?? And you are doing it 6 times each time? The very first thing you should do is `dt1[, y := as.IDate(y)] ; dt2[, y := as.IDate(y)]` before doing any calculations. Secondly, I would try a rolling join here

Comment: Maybe two rolling joins. Something like `indx1 <- dt2[dt1, on = c(x = "x", y = "y"), roll = -3, which = TRUE] ; indx2 <- dt2[dt1, on = c(x = "x", y = "y"), roll = 3, which = TRUE] ; dt1[!is.na(indx1), z := dt2[na.omit(indx1), z]] ; dt1[!is.na(indx2), z := dt2[na.omit(indx2), z]] ; dt1` could give you some ideas. Or maybe try `foverlaps`

Comment: Dates fixed, it probably yields only minor improvement. And thanks for pointers on dt roll argument / foverlaps. I will check them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the [current development version of data.table, v1.9.7](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), then you can use the new conditional joins feature as follows:

```
# v1.9.7+
dt1[dt2, z := i.z, on=.(x, start<=y, end>=y)]
```

This step comes after converting both `y` columns to `Date` and adding `start` and `end` to `dt1` alone.

---

There's a [FR, #1639](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1639) to directly provide expression to the `on` argument so that the entire task can be accomplished as follows:

```
dt1[dt2, z := i.z, on=.(x, y-3<=y, y+3>=y)]
```

I'll see if I can speed it up.

Comment: Is there any estimate on when is 1.9.7 going on Cran? I'd rather use 1.9.6, since I will share my code and rather use non-dev versions.

Comment: Revisited this issue as `data.table` 1.9.8 went on Cran. It appears to work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David Arenburg, here's what I came up with:

```
dt1 <- data.table(x = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c"),
                  y = c("2016-03-01", "2016-05-10", "2016-04-14", "2016-06-25", "2016-01-12"))

dt2 <- data.table(x = c("a", "b", "b", "a"),
                  y = c("2016-05-13", "2016-04-16", "2016-06-20", "2016-02-28"),
                  z = c("1", "1", "2", "3"))

dt1[,y:=as.Date(y)]
dt2[,y:=as.Date(y)]

dt1[,start:=y-3]
dt1[,end:=y+3]

dt2[,start:=y]
dt2[,end:=y]

setkey(dt2, start, end)

dt1 <- foverlaps(dt1, dt2, type="any")
dt1 <- dt1[,.(x = i.x, y = i.y, z)]
dt1[is.na(z),z:="unknown"]
dt1

   x          y       z
1: a 2016-03-01       3
2: a 2016-05-10       1
3: b 2016-04-14       1
4: b 2016-06-25 unknown
5: c 2016-01-12 unknown
```

EDIT: Okay, while this works. It sort of "explodes" on large data sets, reaching RAM limits fairly fast. Still some improvements required.

EDIT2: `setkey` should look like `setkey(dt2, x, start, end)`. Otherwise it will just look up ALL the possible time interval overlaps between data sets, without specifying matching variable. Having over 100k entries on both data sets ensured that it went overboard.

Comment: Did you try mu rolling join solution at all? It should be both efficient memory and speed wise. Also, Aruns solution will be even better.

Comment: Work happened. Couldn't spend more time on researching different approaches. As soon as I find some time, I will update my answer with rolling join too. Thanks again, you gave right pointers and problem is solved.

Comment: You don't really need to research... Just try my code in the comment as is and see how long it takes on your data.